# Understanding this theorem and how to go about proving it surjectivity?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I don't follow understand what this theorem is saying: "Every function $f: A \to{\cal P}(A)$ is not surjective."

Is this saying so for example let A = {1,2,3} then the power set of A is {},{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3} Is this saying that there is no surjective function that takes every element in each of its power sets to atleast 1 element in A?

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I don't think it is. Surjective means that **any** element in the codomain is the image of at least one element in the domain. In this case, surjective would imply that any element in $\;\mathcal P(A)\;$ equals $\;f(a)\;$ , for some $\;a\in A\;$ . In the finite case it is very simple, since there are way more elements in $\;\mathcal P(A)\;$ than in $\;A\;$ ...

Comment: Surjectivitiy would require that for each element  $y \in P(A)$ there is an $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. However, the cardinality of the power set of a given set is greater than the cardinality of the set itself.

Comment: It is saying that any choice of function from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$ will necessarily "miss" having some of the elements in the range as outputs of the function.  For example, $f(1)=\{1\},f(2)=\{2\}$ and $f(3)=\{3\}$ would miss having each of $\emptyset,\{1,2\},\dots,\{1,2,3\}$ as outputs.  For finite sets this should be intuitively obvious since there are strictly more elements in the power set of $A$ than in $A$ itself.  You can only output to as many elements as $A$ has or less but never more.  When $A$ is infinite this becomes more difficult to understand but it remains true regardless.

Comment: @JMoravitz is this because the infinity powerset is a bigger infinity than the infinity of the set A.

Comment: That is the end result, but that is proven *by* and is a *result* of this theorem, not the other way around.

Comment: As for a hint on how to prove this, given a set $A$ and an arbitrary function $f:A\to\mathcal{P}(A)$ the classic proof considers the set $B=\{x~:~x\in A,~x\notin f(x)\}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I see is this saying to consider a set B where its element x is in set A, but is not in the function f(x)? can you elaborate on this is ?

Comment: The set $B$ is the set of all elements of $A$ such that our given function when applied to that element sends it to an image which does not contain said element.  In my example above with $f(1)=\{1\},f(2)=\{2\},f(3)=\{3\}$ our set $B$ would happen to be empty.  In my example below, $g(1)=\{1,3\},g(2)=\emptyset,g(3)=\{2\}$ our set $B$ would contain the elements $2$ and $3$ but would not contain $1$ as an element.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not what it's saying.

It's saying that there is no surjective function taking elements of $A$ to subsets of $A$.  That is, if $f$ is any function that takes elements of $A$ and returns subsets of $A$, it can't return *all* subsets of $A$.

Comment: So like as the other user stated f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2 and f(3) = 3 and so we can't get the {} set or {1,2} or {1,2,3} etc?

Comment: @fwefwf I want to emphasize the point that the choice of $f$ I made was an arbitrary one.  That was only one possible function from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$.  A different function might have had something like $g(1)=\{1,3\}$ and $g(2)=\emptyset$ etc... We could have gotten the empty set as an output and so on, but the point is that regardless which function we actually used we couldn't get *all* of the possible outputs simultaneously, there must always be some missing.

Comment: And similarly for any other attempt.  And, more importantly, even if $A$ is an infinite set this is still true.  This was one of the indications in the 19th century that "infinity" is not a single cardinal number but that there are smaller and larger "infinities".

Answer (score 0):

Considering a map $f : A \to P(A)$ from a set to its power set. What do you think about the subsets of all elements which are not in their image $\{x \in A | x \notin f(x)\}$ ? For example, give it a name and suppose that some element $y\in A$ is sent to it, then see what happens.